# Bit manipulation - replace a "block"

Tags: bit-manipulation

I'm trying to write a function that will replace a certain "block" of size 2^x with a new value.

For example, if I had a number `1110 1000 0010` and I wanted to replace block 2 (max block size of 2^4) with `0110`, I would get `0110 1000 0010`. Likewise, If I wanted the to replace block 2 with `110` (max block size of 2^3) I would get `111 110 000 010`, or `1111 1000 0010`.

```
replace_block (value, x, blockNumber, newValue) {
    value |= ((value >> (blockNumber*x) & ~((1 << x) – 1)) | newValue) << (blockNumber*x)
}

Step by step process of what I'm trying to do with this code:
1. Shift the block we want all the way to the right
2. Mask that block with 0's
3. Mask that block again, but with the new value we want
4. Shift the block all the way back to the original position
5. Or the bits in the block with the original value
```

This is what I have so far but I don't think it's correct.

Note: The rightmost block is block 0.

Comment: For 1110 1000 0010: If the block number starts from 0 on the right with a block size of 2^4 (16 bits) then block 2 is XXXX 1000 0010 which you replace with 0110, and for a block size of 2^3 (8) block 2 should be 111 XXX 000 010 but in your example you replace block 1: 111 010 XXX 010 with 110.  So are you counting with block 0 on the right?

Comment: Yea, it starts from block 0 on the right. Edited my post, sorry.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First we need the mask:  The mask is a set of ones "block size" wide shifted to the right block.

- set of ones "block size" wide: `(1<<size) - 1`
- set of ones "block size" wide shifted to the right place: `((1<<size)-1) << (number*size)`

First we clear the bits in the spot that will be replaced then we stick in the bits we want.

- old value with the masked bits cleared: `oldv & ~mask`
- new value shifted to right place: `newv << (number*size)`
- new value shifted to right place and masked to right width: `(newv<<(number*size)) & mask`
- old bits cleared and new value inserted: `(oldv&~mask) | ((newv<<(number*size))&mask)`

So the bit of code you want is:

```
    mask=(((1<<size)-1)<<(number*size));
    result=((oldv&~mask)|((newv<<(number*size))&mask));
```

A test program:

```
    #include <stdio.h>

    void printbits(int n) {
        unsigned int i = 1<<(sizeof(n) * 8 - 1);
        while (i > 0) {
            if (n & i)
                 printf("1");
            else
                 printf("0");
            i >>= 1;
        }
    }

    int main(void) {

        int size,number,mask,oldv,newv,result;

        size=4;number=2;oldv=0;newv=15;
        mask=(((1<<size)-1)<<(number*size));
        result=((oldv&~mask)|((newv<<(number*size))&mask));
        printf("\nsize   = %d\nnumber = %d",size,number);
        printf("\noldv   = "); printbits(oldv);
        printf("\nnewv   = "); printbits(newv);
        printf("\nmask   = "); printbits(mask);
        printf("\nomask  = "); printbits(oldv&~mask);
        printf("\nnmask  = "); printbits((newv<<(number*size))&mask);
        printf("\nresult = "); printbits(result);
        printf("\n");

        size=4;number=2;oldv=~0;newv=0;
        mask=(((1<<size)-1)<<(number*size));
        result=((oldv&~mask)|((newv<<(number*size))&mask));
        printf("\nsize   = %d\nnumber = %d",size,number);
        printf("\noldv   = "); printbits(oldv);
        printf("\nnewv   = "); printbits(newv);
        printf("\nmask   = "); printbits(mask);
        printf("\nomask  = "); printbits(oldv&~mask);
        printf("\nnmask  = "); printbits((newv<<(number*size))&mask);
        printf("\nresult = "); printbits(result);
        printf("\n");

        size=3;number=2;oldv=0;newv=7;
        mask=(((1<<size)-1)<<(number*size));
        result=((oldv&~mask)|((newv<<(number*size))&mask));
        printf("\nsize   = %d\nnumber = %d",size,number);
        printf("\noldv   = "); printbits(oldv);
        printf("\nnewv   = "); printbits(newv);
        printf("\nmask   = "); printbits(mask);
        printf("\nomask  = "); printbits(oldv&~mask);
        printf("\nnmask  = "); printbits((newv<<(number*size))&mask);
        printf("\nresult = "); printbits(result);
        printf("\n");

        size=3;number=2;oldv=~0;newv=0;
        mask=(((1<<size)-1)<<(number*size));
        result=((oldv&~mask)|((newv<<(number*size))&mask));
        printf("\nsize   = %d\nnumber = %d",size,number);
        printf("\noldv   = "); printbits(oldv);
        printf("\nnewv   = "); printbits(newv);
        printf("\nmask   = "); printbits(mask);
        printf("\nomask  = "); printbits(oldv&~mask);
        printf("\nnmask  = "); printbits((newv<<(number*size))&mask);
        printf("\nresult = "); printbits(result);
        printf("\n");

        size=4;number=4;oldv=0xAAAAAAAA;newv=0x15;
        mask=(((1<<size)-1)<<(number*size));
        result=((oldv&~mask)|((newv<<(number*size))&mask));
        printf("\nsize   = %d\nnumber = %d",size,number);
        printf("\noldv   = "); printbits(oldv);
        printf("\nnewv   = "); printbits(newv);
        printf("\nmask   = "); printbits(mask);
        printf("\nomask  = "); printbits(oldv&~mask);
        printf("\nnmask  = "); printbits((newv<<(number*size))&mask);
        printf("\nresult = "); printbits(result);
        printf("\n");

        size=5;number=3;oldv=0xAAAAAAAA;newv=0x15;
        mask=(((1<<size)-1)<<(number*size));
        result=((oldv&~mask)|((newv<<(number*size))&mask));
        printf("\nsize   = %d\nnumber = %d",size,number);
        printf("\noldv   = "); printbits(oldv);
        printf("\nnewv   = "); printbits(newv);
        printf("\nmask   = "); printbits(mask);
        printf("\nomask  = "); printbits(oldv&~mask);
        printf("\nnmask  = "); printbits((newv<<(number*size))&mask);
        printf("\nresult = "); printbits(result);
        printf("\n");

        return 0;
    }
```

And the result:

```
    size   = 4
    number = 2
    oldv   = 00000000000000000000000000000000
    newv   = 00000000000000000000000000001111
    mask   = 00000000000000000000111100000000
    omask  = 00000000000000000000000000000000
    nmask  = 00000000000000000000111100000000
    result = 00000000000000000000111100000000

    size   = 4
    number = 2
    oldv   = 11111111111111111111111111111111
    newv   = 00000000000000000000000000000000
    mask   = 00000000000000000000111100000000
    omask  = 11111111111111111111000011111111
    nmask  = 00000000000000000000000000000000
    result = 11111111111111111111000011111111

    size   = 3
    number = 2
    oldv   = 00000000000000000000000000000000
    newv   = 00000000000000000000000000000111
    mask   = 00000000000000000000000111000000
    omask  = 00000000000000000000000000000000
    nmask  = 00000000000000000000000111000000
    result = 00000000000000000000000111000000

    size   = 3
    number = 2
    oldv   = 11111111111111111111111111111111
    newv   = 00000000000000000000000000000000
    mask   = 00000000000000000000000111000000
    omask  = 11111111111111111111111000111111
    nmask  = 00000000000000000000000000000000
    result = 11111111111111111111111000111111

    size   = 4
    number = 4
    oldv   = 10101010101010101010101010101010
    newv   = 00000000000000000000000000010101
    mask   = 00000000000011110000000000000000
    omask  = 10101010101000001010101010101010
    nmask  = 00000000000001010000000000000000
    result = 10101010101001011010101010101010

    size   = 5
    number = 3
    oldv   = 10101010101010101010101010101010
    newv   = 00000000000000000000000000010101
    mask   = 00000000000011111000000000000000
    omask  = 10101010101000000010101010101010
    nmask  = 00000000000010101000000000000000
    result = 10101010101010101010101010101010
```

Comment: Nice! However, I don't see the point in `&`ing with 'mask'. If we `&` with a mask, we get the same result. I guess you're assuming that the user might input a new value which is greater than the max value a block size can hold? In that case, we don't want to change the old value anyway.